# Keep Control always on top

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, z-order

Is it possible to keep a control (`Panel`) always over all other controls even if they also use `Control.BringToFront()`?

I tired to use `BringToFront` itself, but it seems that this loose its effectiveness if another control under this control also uses this command.

Comment: No.  Strange to have such unruly controls in your program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would help if you try to explain what are you trying to achieve. We might be then able to better convince you, that you are doing something very wrong :)

Anyway, no matter what trick you do, the other control may use the same trick to override you.

You can get step ahead for example by handling parent control's `Layout` event to force your control back to front. The `Layout` event is trigerred (among other) when child controls' Z-order is changed.

```cs
private void Form1_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BringToFront();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way of dealing with this is setting a timer and everytime it ticks use the .BringToFront() method on the control, you can also add multiple controls you wish to perform this on and can arrange them however you like.